# Tracing with eBPF tracepoint "netif_receive_skb" for multiple NICs

Tags: ebpf, libbpf, tracepoint

I am trying to capture incoming packets with tracepoint events in the net category. As per this [blog](https://blog.packagecloud.io/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-receiving-data/), netif_receive_skb seems to be a suitable tracepoint (one of the earliest points in the networking stack, L4 agnostic as well). Things work as expected with VMs having 1 NIC. However, when there are 2 NICs some packets are not captured meaning that the tracepoint is not triggered. Verifying with tcpdump for the secondary interface, I do see that the packets which are received by the secondary interface are not captured by the tracepoint netif_receive_skb.

My understanding was that the tracepoint was independent of the network interface which is another reason for choosing netif_receive_skb over xdp (additionally, when loading the eBPF program with this tracepoint, network interfaces are not mentioned anyway).

Again referring to the [blog](https://blog.packagecloud.io/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-receiving-data/), I noticed that "netif_receive_skb operates in the context of a the softirq processing loop" which is in turn dependent on the interrupt raised by the network interface on receiving a packet.

Code snippet for the tracepoint:

```
SEC("tp/net/netif_receive_skb")
int net_netif_receive_skb(struct trace_event_raw_consume_skb *args) 
{
    struct sk_buff *skb = (struct sk_buff *)BPF_CORE_READ(args, skbaddr);
    return trace_skb(skb, TP_NETIF_RECEIVE_SKB);
}
```

So the questions are, does each network interface have their individual `netif_receive_skb`  instances or this tracepoint is shared by all the NICs? If `netif_receive_skb`  is for individual interfaces, any idea/pointer/examples for such a program?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Using a tracing hook point to capture packets when you have several networking hook points seems a bit strange.

Comment: Also, note the link to the blog post is missing.

Comment: Added the links to the blogs. I am just trying to capture incoming packets in a node where there could be multiple NICs in the node.  I would like to capture the packets at the earliest point (preferably before L4) in the network stack but avoid ```tc``` or ```xdp``` since they need to be tied to the network interfaces. Any other more suitable hook(s) to do this?